# KEYCODE 9 JQUERY não funciona

Tags: javascript

Olá!

Sabem me dizer porque o evento `keycode == 9` não funciona?

```
$("#txt_cep").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        $("#btn_pesquisa_cep").click();
    } else if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#btn_pesquisa_cep").click();
    }
});
```

O evento `e.which == 13` funciona, mas o `e.keyCode == 9` não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `keypress` vai ser executado enquanto a tecla tiver sendo pressionada, o problema é que ele funciona apenas para valores alfanuméricos, pontuação e etc. Não funciona com `Alt`, `Shift` etc.

Utilize o `keydown`, ela vai ativar o gatilho antes de qualquer outra ação do navegador.

Segundo a documentação¹:

> O evento `keydown` é disparado quando uma tecla é pressionada para baixo. Ao contrário do evento `keypress`, o evento `keydown` é disparado para as chaves que produzem um valor de caractere e para chaves que não produzem um valor de caractere.

```js
$("#txt_cep").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        alert("Tab");
    } else if (e.which == 13) {
        alert("Enter");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="txt_cep" />
```

> **Obs.:** O Chrome não dispara o evento `keypress` para atalhos de teclado conhecidos ¹

<sup>Referência 1: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress</sup>